# Only first N datapoints should be used

Tags: highcharts

I have several 100 data points (type: 'scatter3d'). I do not like how the zoom works, so I would like to change the number of data points that are being used, for example only the first 10. The axis should adjust accordingly. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to provide the proper data to the chart. For example:

```
    var data = [
        ...
    ];

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        ...,
        series: [{
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: data.slice(0, 10)
        }]
    });

    document.getElementById('first').addEventListener('click', function() {
        chart.series[0].setData(data.slice(0, 10));
    });

    document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', function() {
        chart.series[0].setData(data.slice(10, 20));
    });
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9aruwzpd/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData